# Do I really need a MainWindow.xib file?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I have an iPad 4.3 project that doesn't have a MainWindow.xib because it's main view is created programmatically. Everything seems to work fine but I noticed that in my plist file there's a value for a NSMainNibFile key that has "MainWindow" for value. If I change in any way that entry, my app won't work. Now, that's strange, at least for me...

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the xib reference in the target properties, be sure to change your code in main.m to refer to your class delegate class.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"YourAppDelegateClassName");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the NSMainNibFile key from your Info.plist, you need to update the code for main.m.  You will need to update the `NSString *delegateClassName` in the call to [UIApplicationMain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain).

Comment: What is strange is:

1) I don't have a MainWindow.xib file (I deleted it)
2) I haven't removed the NSMainNibFile key from my info.plist file 
3) I did not modify the call to UIApplicationMain:

`[int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

4) The application works as expected!

Comment: If I, however, remove the key, the application fails to work…

Comment: I found my problem. Indeed, I needed the MainWindow.xib file. It was still deployed on the iPad simulator since I hadn't removed the app, so it was found. As soon as I redeployed it, I found it was really needed... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't necessarily need something called `MainWindow.xib` you could rename everywhere but as this answer points out you have to have something for the application to start with; [What's the MainWindow.xib nib file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381474/whats-the-mainwindow-xib-nib-file-for)